# Meteor test if Users datas = "NULL"

Tags: meteor, collections, iron-router, meteor-accounts

I want to test if my currentUser have in his users collection

->     profileType: "NULL" (default value).

and if profileType != "NULL" i will redirect the user to an other template.

I don't where will be the best place to do it ?

- In the router whith a onBeforeAction
- on a client helper
- call a method in the server side

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the behavior you want.

`onBeforeAction` if you put it here, your app will wait and show your loading template while it checks this.

If you put it in a client helper you will have a noticable UI change when the data changes.

If you make a server side method then you should also utilize `onBeforeAction` to wait on your call to be made.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question #Idls, but here's some places to start.

> I want to test if my currentUser have in his users collection
>
> -> profileType: "NULL" (default value).

Look at the Collections2 and SimpleSchema Meteor packages.  [Understand and implement this](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#attach-a-schema-to-meteorusers).

> and if profileType != "NULL" i will redirect the user to an other template.
>
> I don't where will be the best place to do it ?

[This question will help you with that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084419/meteor-user-profile-page-with-iron-router)

Answer (score 0):

By far the simplest and quickest way is just to do it in Blaze:

```
{{#if profileType}}
  {{> nonNullProfileTypeTemplate}}
{{else}}
  {{> nullProfileTypeTemplate}}
{{/if}}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that *null* is false-y.

You could do it in the router too but there's little advantage to that approach in this case IMO.