# Meteor: Get user information from user profile page

Tags: meteor, field, router, helper

I have a Meteor project with a profile page system setup for each user which I created with the help of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084419/meteor-user-profile-page-with-iron-router).

How can I retrieve information from the user's profile for that page in the JS code for my Template.helpers?

Eg.  I have the following helper for my profile page

```
Template.profile.helpers({
  winLoseRatio: function() {
    var wins = 0;
    var losses = 0;

    var ratio = wins/losses;
    ratio = Math.round((ratio * 1000) + 0.000001) / 1000;

    return ratio;
  },
  totalGuesses: function() {
    var wins = 0;
    var losses = 0;

    var total = wins + losses;

    return total;
  }
});
```

For all the values of 0, I want to get the user's (who's profile I'm on) .profile.stats.wins and .profile.stat.losses field values.

I tried `Meteor.userId().profile.stats.wins` but that returned the wins of the current logged in your and not the wins of the user who owns the profile page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All users are available in `Meteor.users` collection, so:

```
// Find user with id of currently viewed profile.
var user = Meteor.users.findOne(userId);
if (user) {
    console.log(user.profile.stats.wins);
} else {
    console.log('No user with id', user);
}
```

Comment: How do I get the userId for that specific profile page?

Comment: There's no `username` word in your post, but ok. Instead of `Meteor.users.findOne(userId)` find your user by username: `Meteor.users.findOne({ username: username })`.

Comment: Ok, sorry - I've just woke up. Did that second `findOne` worked?

Comment: I get a username is not defined error in my client console.

Comment: Ok got it working, I had to pass username as a parameter to the function.   Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.